# What is the difference between invoking a function outside of class vs inside of it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

Experiencing some unexpected functionality with a socket event on the client side. I have two clients joined in a socket.io room. they are successfully joined, as shown in my server console logs. client side, the event is sent successfully and received by the server successfully. the server is sending an event to both clients In the room, the sender and the other client. *only* the sending client receives the first attempt. after said half-failed attempt, if the other client attempts the same socket emission, the server successfully sends to both clients. the `.emit()` and `.on()` are in a component function.

*interestingly*, if the `.on()` for the server event is placed *outside* of the class, everything works fine the very first time.

component:

```
import stuff
const socket = io("http://172.**.**.***:3000");
// example '.on()' that works correctly
socket.on("test", () => {
  alert("response from outside component");
});
export default class Lobby extends React.Component {
  constructor() { }
  onTest(socket) {
    alert("outgoing alert");
    socket.emit("test", {
      room: this.state.room
    });
    // '.on()' that doesn't work correctly
    socket.on("test", () => {
      alert("incoming client alert")
    });
  }
  render() {
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTest(socket)}>
        <Text>Press me </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 
  }
```

server event:

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("user connected with socket id:" + socket.id);
  socket.on("test", test => {
    console.log(received from client, emitting to room #:" + test.room);
    io.to(test.room).emit("test");
  });
}
```

Comment: switch the order and your code will work, i.e `socket.emit` under `socket.on`, but will add duplicate events on each click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause for the client that hasn't send anything yet, `omTest` was not yet called, and thus `socket.on("test", ...)` was not executed and no handler was added, therefore no one is handling the incoming message and it looks as if it did not arrive. You should always directly attach handlers when you set up the socket.

Comment: Any recommended material on what you’re talking about?